# drupal ahah not working

Tags: 6, ajax

I'm trying to make a ahah form. the problem is the ahah is ignored. when i check the classes on the submit button, it doesn't have the 'ahah-processed' class. The really interesting thing is that ahah is working perfectly on my site, and even on a nearly identical form I created. this is how i'm creating the ahah submit button:

```
$form['ri_email_submit'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#value' => t('Submit'),
        '#weight' => 1,
        '#submit' => array('ri_email_form_submit'),//none JS version
        '#ahah' => array(
          'event' => 'click',
          'path' => 'ri_email/ajax',
          'wrapper' => 'email-friend-wrap',
          'method' => 'replace',
          'effect' => 'fade',
          'progress' => array(
            'type' => 'bar',
            'message' => t('Loading...')
          )      
        )
        );
```

I checked the menu path, it's correct.

UPDATE: this is the menu callback:

```
function ri_email_ajax() {
    return drupal_json(array('status' => TRUE, 'data' => '<p><strong>Your email has been sent.</strong><p>'));   }
```

by the way, i discovered that it didn't work when i invoked drupal_get_form() from page.tpl.php, but it does work from node.tpl.php

there is something missing with the javascript that is supposed to handle the ahah

Comment: I second your request Chapabu.

Answer (score 1):

Can you post the callback function generating the page at 'ri_email/ajax'?

It should look something like this:

```
<?php
  function awesome_ahah_callback() {
    $thing_to_process = $_POST['thingfromform']
    /* do stuff, including generating some kind of $processed_data variable */

    drupal_json(array(
      'status' => TRUE, 
      'data' => $processed_data,
    ));
    exit();
  }
?>
```

If you aren't generating the thing you want to send back through AHAH with drupal_json and then calling exit() then I don't think it will work.